# Movie where a blind girl has three guys trying to kill her, shoots them with revolver after sensing them

Tags: story-identification, movie, actors

I remember watching a movie where a young girl (16-21 probably) is blind. Even though I don't remember the whole movie the ending of the movie was that there's a house where the final scene takes place and there are three guys trying to kill her.

I think she is left upstairs and these guys come searching for her. Luckily, she has a revolver and tries to shoot them, but runs out of bullets and starts loading it. After reloading, she manages to shoot each of them after identifying them through some echolocation technique or some other technique that blind people use. I watched it between 2008-2011. On TV. It was in English.

I dont know if there was some cgi or not.But I guess maybe there is . Not sure.

Comment: Do you remember this "echo technique" in any more detail? I think I've sort of seen a blind person do this before in real life so not sure if this is SFF-nal as it stands.

Comment: Maybe. I think she is left upstairs and these guys they come searching for her and she just feels them coming near them I rememer.

Comment: Can it be _Lost in the Dark_? It aired it 2007, and features a blind woman who shots a guy in the chest.

Comment: I'm not seeing a science fiction or fantasy element in this.  Echo location is a real technique, one even sighted people can learn, and I don't see anything else here beyond a suspense/action film with a slightly unusual premise.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I personally came to the same conclusion as you but depending on how the "echo technique" works this could be SFF-nal so decided to give it the benefit of the doubt until a answer is accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [*Lost in the Dark*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1071810/)

This was a television film that aired originally in 2007. It has also been entitled *Enemy Within*.

The synopsis below is quite long and the last paragraph is the one that contains the details you remember but it all ties together so seems relevant to add everything in. Emphasis mine for the parts that match your description.

> A young girl, Amy Tolliver (Mae Whitman), is visiting her grandmother's cabin in a forested mountain area of Maine. Amy has developed a degenerative eye disease that has made her completely blind, and she is trying to cope with her recent handicap. When her boyfriend, David (Matthew Smalley), leaves for supplies, she is left alone. A heavy storm develops and two escaped convicts, Roy (Jason Gray-Stanford and Jared Teach Grant) come to the isolated cabin. Amy must try to outwit the two convicts in order to survive.[1] After Amy drops several clues over phone calls to both her boyfriend and the police, a police officer arrives at the cabin, just as Amy discovers her grandmother dead in the bathtub. However, Roy shoots the police officer and Amy is in peril once more when Roy cannot escape in the police car. One of the other convicts, Jared arrives just after Amy tricks Roy into going into the log store and locks him in, and takes her back into the house, pretending to be a police officer.
>
> Meanwhile, Amy's boyfriend is making his way to the cabin, having had to leave his car because of a fallen tree, and the police aren't far behind. The police discover that the two convicts who are still roaming around are brothers, in prison for armed robbery and murder. Amy almost manages to convince Jared that Roy has moved on, until Roy fires a gun at the lock on the store, alerting Jared, who was about to drive off. Amy also hears the gunshots, and tries to escape, but the brothers catch her. She tries to play them off against each other, telling Jared that Roy was going to leave without him, but it doesn't work.
>
> David arrives at the cabin just as the brothers are about to shoot her. David shuts the electricity off and Roy misses the shot, saving Amy's life. The brothers try to find Amy, realising that they haven't killed her, but while they can't see her, Amy uses her other senses to navigate, evading them. Amy hits Jared with a fire poker, knocking him out, while David tries to attack Roy. Roy catches him and holds him at gunpoint, telling Amy to come out or he'll kill David. He shoots David in the leg and knocks him unconscious. **Amy picks up Jared's gun**, and the two try to navigate in the darkness and find the other. Roy accidentally shoots Jared, thinking that he's Amy, and Jared dies in his arms. **Amy hides upstairs and Roy angrily pursues her**, as the police arrive. **Amy loads Jared's gun with bullets just as Roy climbs the stairs, and shoots him in the chest just as he prepares to shoot her.** However, it isn't fatal, and Roy tries to shoot her again, but the Sheriff shoots him from downstairs. Amy rides off in the ambulance with David.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *Lost in the Dark* (2007 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_in_the_Dark_(2007_film))</sub>

Comment: Hmm...I am not sure, but yes this has a bigger probability . And Thank you

Comment: @BLASTERS I haven't seen the film but the description does match quite well, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for the late reply if.